# multiple regression

Tags: multiple-regression, interaction, difference-in-difference

When we run a regression using slightly different equations, each an equation gives, to some extent, different results.

For example, y=a+b1X1+b2X2+b3X1*X2    or
                         y=a+b1X1+b2X2+b3X1*X2*X4

When we add additional independent or control variable, this sometimes causes some changes in the results.
So, how can I know the best model/equation (among those equations)?

Also, in case of there is an interaction between two variables such as:
 y=a+b1X1+b2X2+b3X1*X2

and I want to add additional interaction such as:
b3X1*X2*X4   to the model,

Shall I keep the original interaction (b3X1*X2) or I have to exclude it from the model?